# How to replace a single string in a list in Python?

Tags: python

If I had a list, would I be able to replace a string in the list without replacing other strings of the same value?

For example, in the list:

```
list1=['Mon', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed']
```

How can I replace the first 'Mon' to 'Monday' without replacing the second 'Mon'?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to replace the first? Or the last? Or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Well, you've got to decide somehow which one you want to replace, and I don't see how you want to do that without knowing the index of your choice.

Comment: @cold dont know if edit was made in grace period, but OP said the first occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` method. It returns the first occurrence of the element in the `list` *after a specific starting position*. The starting position, if left undefined, defaults to `0`; i.e., the beginning of the `list`.

```
list1=['Mon', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed']
try:
    index = list1.index('Mon')
    list1[index] = 'Monday'
except ValueError:
    print('Mon not found')
```

Comment: You'll want the assignment in the try too, otherwise index is undefined

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it

Comment: Nice use of `else`!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Guess it's a matter of taste, I like to make it as explicit as possible on which line an exception can occur, by making the bit in the try: as short as possible.

Comment: @NickA That is wrong. `else` executes only if the `try` succeeds (in which case, `index` would be defined here.)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich You are right. I got mislead by Nick's comment. Sorry.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Don't know why you're blaming me, the else wasn't in the answer when I commented ;) the assignment was outside the whole block

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the index of the element you want to change, simply change it by -

```
list1=['Mon', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed']
list1[0] = 'Monday'
```

In case you don't have the index already, use the `index` function.The index function finds the first match and returns the index. In case you don't know whether `Mon` is there in your list, you can use @Vladyslav Ushakov's method or you can check if `'Mon'` is present in `list1`

```
if 'Mon' in list1:
    list1[list1.index('Mon')] = 'Monday'

print(list1)
# ['Monday', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed']
```